# How does SQL Agent handle scheduling Monthly on 31st given some Months don't have 31st?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Let's say I create a SQL Agent job to have 3 schedules (Monthly 29th, Monthly 30th, Monthly 31st).

For Feb which ends on the 28th, I'm presuming SQL Agent will handle the transition from the end of Feb to March by essentially doing nothing since no Feb 29th occurs.

I'm almost certain of the behavior, but don't have a way to test it (that I can think of). Can someone please confirm that have done this?

Comment: You could just schedule last day of month and use logic in the sql code executed (or stored procedure) to determine if you want to do anything.

Comment: Agreed, but was preferring to do it this way. Instead of maintaining additional code or logic outside of the steps already there.